# Terraform GCP Assign IAM roles to service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-iam

I'm using the following

```
resource "google_service_account" "store_user" {
  account_id   = "store-user"
  display_name = "Storage User"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "store_user" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "roles/storage.admin"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}"
  ]
}
```

Which works well, in that it creates the SA and assigns it the storage admin role. Great.
But I need to give this SA about 4 roles. I have tried all manner of things, including using a data block with repeating bindings/roles blocks like this:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "store_user_roles" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/storage.admin"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}",
    ]
  }
  binding {
    role = "roles/pubsub.admin"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}",
    ]
  }
}
```

Oddly, that runs, but the SA does not get the roles/permissions. I've tried various other examples I've found here and there but with no success. Can someone please give me a shove in the right direction for how to accomplish this?

// Update. The following did work for me:

```
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "storage-iam" {
    project = var.project_id
    role = "roles/storage.admin"
    members = [
        "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}",
    ]
}
resource "google_project_iam_binding" "pubsub-iam" {
    project = var.project_id
    role = "roles/pubsub.admin"
    members = [
        "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another alternate would be to use a loop. Here is some sample code using a `count` loop.

variables.tf

```
variable "rolesList" {
type =list(string)
default = ["roles/storage.admin","roles/pubsub.admin"]
}
```

service-account.tf

```
resource "google_service_account" "store_user" {
account_id   = "store-user"
display_name = "Storage User"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "store_user" {
project = var.project_id
count = length(var.rolesList)
role =  var.rolesList[count.index]
members = [
  "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}"
]
}
```

Please note that when using a `count` loop, Terraform maintains a map of index with the values in the state file. In simpler terms, if you remove the 1st element from the list simply because we don't want the role then Terraform will remove all the elements from index 2 (of the older list) and then apply them back.

Also, I prefer using `google_project_iam_member` instead of `google_project_iam_binding` because when using `google_project_iam_binding` if there are any users or SAs created outside of Terraform bound to the same role, GCP would remove them on future runs (TF Apply).

Comment: Thanks. In my case the bindings block you provided was key, I did not use the loop, but two distinct blocks each with a role did the trick.

Comment: `google_project_iam_binding` uses the setIamPolicy APIa. We can find more of the underlying API from https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/setIamPolicy

Answer (score 3):

I think this is achieved with this resource:

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_service_account_iam

So with your code, minus the data sources, alter to taste:

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "storage-iam" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.store_user.name
  role               = "roles/storage.admin"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}",
  ]
}

resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "pubsub-iam" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.store_user.name
  role               = "roles/pubsub.admin"

  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. In my case although this code ran ok, it did not actually apply the roles (only the first one). I've updated the question to show what eventually worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are another 2 ways to do this:

1. Use for_each variable and set the strings inside `google_project_iam_binding`

   ```
   resource "google_project_iam_binding" "store_user" {
      project  = var.project_id
      for_each = toset([
        "roles/storage.admin",
        "roles/pubsub.admin",
      ])
      role     = each.value
      members  = [
         "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}"
      ]
    }
   ```
2. Define a sa_roles variable and use it with for_each in `google_project_iam_binding`

   ```
   variable "sa_roles" {
     type = set(string)
     default = [
      "roles/storage.admin",
      "roles/pubsub.admin",
     ]
   }

   resource "google_project_iam_binding" "store_user" {
     project  = var.project_id
     for_each = var.sa_roles
     role     = each.value
     members  = [
      "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.store_user.email}"
     ]
   }
   ```